# Facing problem in integrating my angularjs with java maven using docker

Tags: java, angular, docker, maven, nginx

I have my front-end in Angular and back-end REST services written in java using maven plugin. I want to containerise the web service using docker but I am stuck on how to connect my front-end and back-end(which contains the webapp(WAR) of my RESTAPIs) in Dockerfile.

Should I use nginx as a mediator between the two?
Any suggestions. Thanks in advance.
I have written my Dockerfile below !

```
FROM node:alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install && \
npm build
FROM tomcat
COPY --from=builder Example.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/Example.war
```

Answer (score 0):

Wars are web-archives that can be deployed on dedicated application server like tomcat, weblogic or many others. Application can't be run as standalone from var. If you want to run it from docker container - most widely used option is [spring boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/)  Has a nice [docker tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/) as well. Then you can connect your web app by directly exposing app port on the back-end (suggest this approach for a play around at the beginning).